# Is google translate an accurate device to translate english to japanese? (and vice-versa)

Tags: discussion

Is google translate an accurate device to translate english to japanese (and vice versa)? Or does it alters the meaning with a high rate?

Here are a few examples of english to japanese(note that i don't know whether they are right or not, I just started taking classes, and wanted to complement it with self-study):

1) I want to study japanese. / 私は日本語を勉強したいと思います。/Watashi wa nihongo o benkyō shitai to omoimasu.

2) I can't give up when the going gets tough./進行は厳しい取得したときに、私はあきらめることはできません。/Shinkō wa kibishī shutoku shita toki ni, watashi wa akirameru koto wa dekimasen.

3)I'm going to travel to japan next year, at spring time./私は春の時点で、来年日本に旅行するつもりです。/Watashi wa haru no jiten de, rainen'nihon ni ryokō suru tsumoridesu.

Are these translations accurate? There is a "slang" in item 2, "the going gets tough", I wonder if the japanese translation was appropriate.

Thank you.

Comment: Machine translation performs very poorly with natural languages in general. Google Translate's English–Japanese is no exception. If you [search this site for "google translate"](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=google+translate) you'll find many poorly translated samples and the caveat "(almost) never trust Google Translate"...

Comment: No.............

Comment: If your goal is to learn Japanese by reading English sentences and their Japanese equivalents, I would recommend finding a parallel-text reader. For example, ["Breaking into Japanese Literature: Seven Modern Classics in Parallel Text"](http://www.amazon.com/Breaking-into-Japanese-Literature-Classics/dp/1568364156) - I haven't read this one, but I did flip through it at a book store once, and it looked pretty good. Trying to construct parallel texts via Google Translate is... less than a good idea.

Comment: I second @senshin's recommendation. I purchased it once and it was excellent.